# Get-ProcessesByName in powershell to monitor individual python scripts running

Tags: powershell, process-monitoring, windows-process

I want to monitor python scripts in powershell. For that I am using `Get-ProcessByName`. I want to monitor individual python and JAVA scripts running and store its processId in a csv file according to individual script running. `Get-ProcessByName` lists all the the python or JAVA processes in the same row. How do I separate all the script names in different rows. What I am currently doing is-

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]
$outputTime = $process::GetProcessesByName($processName.ProcessName)[0].TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds
$name = ($process::GetProcessesByName($processName.ProcessName)[0]) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessName
$extra = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name = '$name.exe'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CommandLine
```

Here in `$extra` I am getting names of all the python scripts.How do I seperate all the scripts

Comment: What were you expecting the variable to contain?

Comment: What does `$extra.GetType()` return? I would assume it's an array you can loop over any way you want.

Comment: I am trying to monitor some processes like JAVA, Python and collect all the scripts running in a csv. Now I want to add the names of the python or JAVA script separately in the csv in individual rows based on there processIDs. the variable contains all the list of the scripts running under python or java. I want to seperate all the script names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding `Win32_Process` already has all the information you need. You can use `Select-Object` and `Calculated Properties` to modify if required.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'python.exe'} | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, 
        @{Name         = 'Script'
          Expression   = {$_.CommandLine -replace 
                          '(.*)\\(?<py>.*\.py)|(.*)\ (?<py>.*\.py.*)', 
                          '${py}'}
        }, 
        @{
            Name       = 'CpuTime'
            Expression = {($_.KernalModeTime + $_.UserModeTime) / 10000000} 
        } | 
    Sort-Object -Property CpuTime -Descending
```

This would output something like

```
    Name       Script                 CpuTime
    ----       ------                 -------
    python.exe completion.py preview  1,65625
    python.exe Untitled-1.py         0,015625
```

Of course this would work for `java.exe` or other, even multiple processes, as well. If you dont want to output the full `CommandLine` replace the first `Calculated Property` with `CommandLine`.

Comment: what if I want to exclude some specific set of python scripts. lets say untitled-1.py and print rest all scripts. how to do that?

Comment: Add a `Where-Object` filter to the pipline (like `Where-Object Script -ne untitled-1.py`)

Comment: How to get Process ID (PID) of these processes?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this

```
Get-Process | where ProcessName -Match python
```

Comment: I have to monitor many processes, not only python. and that too individual scripts running under python or other processes